# What do I need to draw the image?

Tags: dart, drawimage

The following code should draw an image while the mouse moves in a canvas after selecting it in a toolbar:

```dart
import 'dart:html';


    class Test {
      ImageElement toolbar_selected_element = new ImageElement();
      CanvasElement canvas;
      var loaded_image_toolbar = false;
      var mouseX = null, mouseY = null;

      void main() {
        canvas = query("#canvas");
        canvas.onMouseMove.listen(canvas_OnMouseMove);
        query(".toolbuton").onDragStart.listen(toolbar_button_OnClick);
      }

      void toolbar_button_OnClick(MouseEvent event) {
        toolbar_selected_element.onLoad.listen(tool_button_image_OnLoad);
        toolbar_selected_element.src = event.target.src;
       }

      void tool_button_image_OnLoad(event) {
        loaded_image_toolbar = true;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }

      void canvas_OnMouseMove(MouseEvent event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }

      void draw(num _) {
        if(loaded_image_toolbar && mouseX != null && mouseY != null) {
          CanvasRenderingContext2D context = canvas.context2d;
          context.drawImage(toolbar_selected_element, mouseX, mouseY);
        }
      }
    }

    void main() {
      new Test().main();
    }
```

The draw method is invoked but the image does not show in the canvas, what am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the element class is actually `toolbutton` rather than `toolbuton`.

Your Dart code works (more or less) for me with an HTML body like this:

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <img class="toolbuton" src="./test.png" />
</body>
```

Of course, since you want to select between different images (I think...), this is more like it:

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <img class="toolbutton" src="./test.png" />
  <img class="toolbutton" src="./test2.png" />
</body>
```

And then in `Test.main()`, add a listener for each toolbutton, rather than just the first:

```dart
for (var toolbutton in queryAll('.toolbutton')) {
  toolbutton.onClick.listen(toolbar_button_OnClick);
}
```

I then click on either image and get it drawn in the cursor position in the canvas, and I can switch back and forth between them, which I believe is what you were going for.